# How to publish a jar after obfuscating in gradle plugin project?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, proguard, obfuscation, gradle-plugin

I have created a **gradle plugin** project using **java language** and looking to publish the generated jar after obfuscating but not able to get related document in gradle help page.

I have googled but getting android related configuration setup, is there any inbuilt functionality available to obfuscate in gradle during compile and jar creation? can anyone help?

This is  my plugin project build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1'
}
gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        greeting {
            id = 'com.zo.sign'
            implementationClass = 'signpackage.SignPackagePlugin'
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.zo.sign'
            artifactId = 'signpkg'
            version = '1.0'
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            // change URLs to point to your repos, e.g. http://my.org/repo
            def releasesRepoUrl = layout.buildDirectory.dir('repos/releases')
            def snapshotsRepoUrl = layout.buildDirectory.dir('repos/snapshots')
            url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your buildscript that include the relevant parts. I can say that there is no built-in obfuscation functionality, but it can be achieved using plugins. However, stackoverflow is not a search engine, we can help if you have problems with your buildscript, but usually nobody will write a complete example build script just for you.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64355998/proguard-example-for-gradle-java-application

Comment: @LeonardBrünings Thank you for the reply, I have edited my post by adding build.grade.